# Can we use "comma" and "or" in a single sentense at the same time

Tags: british-english

You can select a document type, e.g. Invoice or Receipt, Bank or Card Statement, Other Document upon upload. If left blank, Receipt Bot will classify the documents automatically based on the content

Answer (score 1):

Your question is based on a false premise, as "or" and the commas are being used for completely different reasons. They are not being used interchangeably.

As I read it, Receipt Bot lists three possible choices:

> - Invoice or Receipt
> - Bank or Card Statement
> - Other Document

In other words, "or" is not being used in a grammatical sense, but simply because it is **part of the name of the option**.

---

Tangentially, I would've preferred to see the options wrapped in quotes, to make this easier to understand:

> e.g. "Invoice or Receipt", "Bank or Card Statement", "Other Document" upon upload

But I'm not sure if that's grammatically more correct. In my opinion, it should at least be *preferred*, in order to improve readability.

Comment: This could also be read as: 1) Invoice; or 2) Receipt, Bank; or 3) Card Statement, Other Document. OP should clarify.

Comment: @Davo: the construction "A or B or C" (when more than two options are presented) is far less common than "A, B, C". I'm not saying you're definitively wrong, but my grouping makes much more semantical sense too. Invoices and receipts are pretty much the same thing anyway (from an accountant's perspective), and "bank" makes little sense but "bank statement" does, which implies that "bank or card statements" is the correct grouping.

Comment: Absolutely, your interpretation is how I read it. I was just indicating that there was another possibility.